# Coroutine method doesn't get called after subscribing to Func event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates

In Unity, I have the following script which contains a func that takes in a Vector2 as an argument and returns IEnumerator

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Func<Vector2, IEnumerator> OnFire;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Fire();
    }

    private void Fire()
    {
        Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);

        if (OnFire != null)
        {
            OnFire.Invoke(mousePosition);
        }
    }
}
```

In my other script, I have a Coroutine that subscribes to that method

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{

    private void Start()
    {
        Weapon.OnFire += ShootAt;
    }

    private IEnumerator ShootAt(Vector2 target)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
        print("Shot at " + target);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Weapon.OnFire -= ShootAt;
    }

}
```

But the ShootAt method in my Bullet script never gets called. It's as if it's not even subscribing to the event. I don't have any compile errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ShootAt` function you are subscribing to the `OnFire` event is not a normal function. It's a coroutine function which requires the use of [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) to call it. Put your `OnFire.Invoke` call inside the `StartCoroutine` function and it should work.

Replace

```
OnFire.Invoke(mousePosition);
```

with

```
StartCoroutine(OnFire.Invoke(mousePosition));
```